# How do I test promise methods that have an inner promise with Jasmine/Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a service function, like so:

```
asyncGetStuff: (id) ->
   stuff = []
   @asyncGetItem id
   .then (item) ->
     #parse some data
     stuff.push data
     return stuff
```

Now I want to test the content of 'stuff':

```
describe "Stuff Service", () ->
  beforeEach module 'MyServices'

  $scope = undefined
  $q = undefined
  stuffSvc = undefined
  itemSvc = undefined

mockItem = {
  item: 'blah blah blah'
}
mockStuff: {
  stuff: 'foo'
}

beforeEach inject ($rootScope, _$q_, _stuffSvc_, _itemSvc_) ->
  $scope = $rootScope.$new()
  $q = _$q_
  stuffSvc = _stuffSvc_
  itemSvc = _itemSvc_

describe "async Stuff Method", () ->
  beforeEach () ->
    deferred = $q.defer()
    deferred.resolve mockItem
    spyOn(itemSvc, 'asyncGetItem').and.returnValue deferred.promise
    $scope.$apply()

  it "should call asyncGetItem", () ->
    stuffSvc.asyncGetStuff()
    expect(itemSvc.asyncGetItem).toHaveBeenCalled() ## this asserts properly

  it "should return a promise", () ->
    promise = stuffSvc.asyncGetStuff()
    expect(promise.then).toBeDefined() ## this asserts properly

  # how to access stuff returned by asyncGetStuff?
    promise = stuffSvc.asyncGetStuff()

    ## I'm sure this is wrong
    promise.then (stuff) -> expect(stuff).toEqual(mockStuff) ## this is ignored
```

I would like to test that the object that is resolved by asyncGetStuff has been processed correctly, but I can't seem to access that value. I know that the nested async method is resolving the promise correctly, but beyond that I am lost.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `done` parameter:

```
it("should return a promise", function(done) {
    var promise = stuffSvc.asyncGetStuff();
    promise.then(function(stuff) {
        expect(stuff).toEqual(mockStuff);
        done(); // letting jasmine know you've finished the test
    });
});
```

Comment: That doesn't work, I get 

    "Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL".

The jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL. is 5 seconds, which is more than enough time for the async method to be invoked. I also tried (desperately) to call $scope.$apply() before invoking done().

Comment: I am sure the inner promise is being resolved. I am not sure the getStuff function is being resolved, but it **should** be resolved. Once the getItem function is resolved (in beforeEach) the data should be available to the remaining getStuff code which simply loops over the data and returns the processed data.